# Problema al validar archivo - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando validar inputs para generar array de archivos.

> FrontEnd

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="archivo[]">
```

> BackEnd

Estoy intentando validar de la siguiente forma.

Lamentablemente no me guarda mi archivo si lo hago así:

```
foreach($files as $key => $file){
  if($request->hasFile($file)){
  ...
  }
}
```

Si no hago validación, es decir:

```
foreach($files as $key => $file){
 ...
}
```

Me funciona perfectamente, entonces... ¿Como deberia validar esta información?

Answer (score 0):

El método `hasFile()` recibe como parámetro el **nombre** del atributo que contiene el archivo, en tu caso tu estás pasando una variable. Prueba del siguiente modo:

```php
public function myMethod(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('files'))
    {
        $files = $request->file('files');

        foreach($files as $key => $file)
        {
            //   ...
        }
    }
}
```

Para más información, revisa [esta](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) sección de la documentación.